# How to force manual reconnect in OpenWRT PPPoE connection mode?

Tags: networking, openwrt

I have a WRT54GL running OpenWRT 10.03.1 ("Backfire").  The router is set in the PPPoE mode, which is connected via Ethernet to the DSL modem.

In order to change my external IP, I need to reset either the modem or the router so the new connection is made with new IP.

Is there a way to use Luci (the web GUI) to do this?

Comment: Thanks to [bbaja42](http://superuser.com/users/8238/bbaja42) for asking this question for DD-WRT; I based my question on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through Luci by following these steps:

1. Log into Luci
2. Make sure you are in the **Status** page (the default)
3. Click on the **Processes** tab
4. Find `/usr/sbin/pppd` in the list and click the [Hang Up] button.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Looks awesome! Thanks for the improvement! +1!